# Preferred way of removing left recursion of EBNF

Tags: context-free-grammar, ebnf, left-recursion

Many textbooks propose different techniques of removing left recursion. Some of them alter the associativity, which is something I would like to avoid.

What is the most straightforward way to remove left recursion in the following (example) grammar?

```
logical_or_expression
    = logical_and_expression
    | logical_or_expression , "||" , logical_and_expression
    ;
```

The example is written in extended backus-naur form and taken from the C grammar of Annex A in the C11 standard. This is done for the sake of transforming the grammar into EBNF for recursive-descent parsing.

My take on the problem:

```
logical_or_expression
    = logical_and_expression, { "||" , logical_and_expression }
    ;
```

But does this preserve the left-associativity of `logical_or_expression`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you meant

```
logical_or_expression
    = { logical_and_expression, "||" } , logical_and_expression
    ;
```

Because otherwise, you haven't removed the left-recursion at all. But that is not really suitable for recursive parsing either, since you cannot tell from the first token of the `logical_or_expression` whether or not the repeated clause should be predicted. That's why the usual style is

```
logical_or_expression
    = logical_and_expression, { "||" , logical_and_expression }
    ;
```

Unfortunately, it is reasonable to say that the above does not preserve left-associativity. However, there is also a sense in which the `{ ... }` EBNF syntax fails to define associativity at all. The first interpretation (that the syntax is inherently right-associative) comes from the special status of the first `logical_and_expression`; the second interpretation (that the syntax fails to specify associativity) comes from the lack of defined ordering of the repetition operator. [Note 1]

Personally, I prefer adding an "interpolation" (or "separated repetition") syntax, which would allow a simpler expression of separated lists:

```
logical_or_expression
    = { logical_and_expression // "||" }
    ;
```

Or:

```
argument_list
    = { expression // "," }
    ;
```

There's no inherent reason not to define an interpolation operator, and some varieties of augmented BNF do have such a thing. [Notes 2&3] This still doesn't clearly specify associativity, but it has two advantages: (1) it's shorter, and (2) it doesn't artificially privilege the first element of the list.

When repetition (of any form) is translated back into BNF, a decision needs to be made as to whether the repetition is left- or right-recursive, which is also a decision about whether the repetition is left- or right-associative. If one were to translate a repetition operator into BNF prior to building a recursive-descent parser, there would be no option other than to use the right-{recursive/associative} version. However, the actual code in a recursive descent parser could work either way:

```
# Recognize A_list == { A // sep }
# Iterative version, left associative
def parse_A_list():
  x = parse_A()
  while next() == sep:
    accept(sep)
    x = new_A_list(x, parse_A())

// Recursive version, right associative
def parse_A_list():
  x = parse_A()
  if next() == sep:
    accept(sep)
    x = new_A_list(x, parse_A_list())
  return x
```

---

#### Notes

1. In [Modern Programming Languages, 2d Edition](http://www.webber-labs.com/mpl/), Chapter 3, page 40, the author suggests that you could:

   > Define a convention: for example, that the form
   > `<exp> ::= <mulexp> { + <mulexp>}`
   > will be used only for left-associative operators

   although he also suggests the strategy of explicitly describing associativity in an associated paragraph of English text.

   I don't know of any commonly-used formalism which uses the first convention (and I find it unnatural) but it at least illustrates the point that EBNF *by itself* does not adequately define associativity of repetition.
2. For example, the [Syntax Definition Format (SDF)](http://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Edaybuild/daily-books/syntax/sdf/sdf.html#section.lists) uses braces to indicate a separated repetition; the last element inside the brace must be a non-terminal and is used as the separator. You still need a repetition operator, either `*` or `+`, so what I wrote as `{ A // a }` would be written in SDF as `{ A a }+`, whereas I would write there `{ A a }*` as `[{ A // a }]`. These differences are not particularly relevant.
3. As another example, W3C uses (or used at some time) a variant of the [ABNF (RFC 5234)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234) formalism in which `#X` indicates a list of `X`s separated specifically by commas. (And also `n#mX` for numbers `n` and `m` indicating the minimum and maximum number of repetitions.)

Comment: Great answer! Your Python snipped implies, that you like to fix left-recursion by simply making the parser iterative at that point?

Comment: @Leandros: I don't use recursive descent parsers much, but if I were writing one, that's how I would write it. If you use an LR parser generator, you can write a grammar which accurately describes the language; of course, you have to then write out repetitions, which is a bit wordy but completely explicit.

Comment: This is also the suggested way of getting rid of left-recursion by some parser generators, for example leg (http://piumarta.com/software/peg/peg.1.html scroll down to diagnostics).